# Windows Metro: Is XPath binding supported in XAML

Tags: xaml, xpath, windows-8, microsoft-metro

New to Windows Metro Programming.

I would like to associate XML data with UI XAML.

It is possible in Windows 8 Application by defining dataProvider:

XmlDataProvider x:Key="InventoryData" XPath="Inventory/Books"

And Binding to UI as:

```
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}"
           XPath="*[@Stock='out'] | *[@Number>=8 or @Number=3]"/>
```

Trying to do the same using VS2012 RC for Windows Metro C# application.

Error in XAML: type 'XmlDataProvider' was not found.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XPath` property is part of the [`Binding` class in WPF xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613500.aspx).  The [metro `Binding` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx#properties) does not have this property.  There is an example of how to extend the WPF implementation of this [here](http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/xpath-variabledynamic-parameters-in-wpf-binding/) that you could probably port to metro.

Comment: You are right, Metro Binding class does not support XPath property.

Comment: Can you elaborate porting solution little more please. As I understand in absence of XMLDataProvider, one needs to implement custom class which encapsulates the XMLdata and implements : IValueConverter interface. right? What would be the UIBinding in this case? or converter would suffice? <br/> All help is appreciated, trying to find my feet with Metro development.

Comment: My recommendation would be to put all your document functionality in a property and then bind to that.